# XML-Schema enumeration of possible values in another file

Tags: xml, xsd, enumeration

i have a question regarding XML type definition and value enumeration in special:
Is it possible to reference an additional file which holds the possible values for a type, within an enumeration section?
My problem is, that I have to define types which have hundreds of possible values and moreover the number of possible values change dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to reference an additional file which holds the possible values for a type, within an enumeration section?

Technically, yes. As @fly_ua pointed out, you can use `xs:import` or `xs:include` to import/include other XML Schema files into your schema.

Further options are using XML entities or something like [XInclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/), but I won't recommend doing so as it will likely cause troubles for XML Schema processors.

> My problem is, that I have to define types which have hundreds of possible values and moreover the number of possible values change dynamically.

I'd strongly discourage using `xs:enumeration`s for this case. Enums should be used if the values are fixed and known in advance. This is part of the schema, so if you change these values, you'll have to change the schema.

You are looking for some kind of easy dynamic way. So that you won't have to change the schema when values change, "just that external file".

There is no "easy dynamic way".

If these values are the part of the schema, then fix them and add them to the schema. It's quite easy but not dynamic.

If these values must be dynamic, then either you have to issue new version of your schema every time anything changes or you they're not a part of a schema.

Here's an example from GML 3.2.1. They define a type called `CodeType`:

```
    <complexType name="CodeType">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>gml:CodeType is a generalized type to be used for a term, keyword or name.
It adds a XML attribute codeSpace to a term, where the value of the codeSpace attribute (if present) shall indicate a dictionary, thesaurus, classification scheme, authority, or pattern for the term.</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="string">
                <attribute name="codeSpace" type="anyURI"/>
            </extension>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
```

It's a simple content type with an additional `codeSpace` attribute. That code space logicalz identifies a set of codes which may be used in this case. Technically this may be an URl of some dictionary file or an ID of a well-known code list.

Just making the enum list external to the schema and change it at will will break applications working with XML instances unless they follow each and every change in your schema. Which may be quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

The option is to use xs:import or xs:include but in this case you have to store some complete type in separate file and keep an eye on file sharing - e.g. XSD loads data - something writes to file.

Another option - dynamically change enum definition - you have to load XmlSchema in your app, navigate to enum definition facet and add values from your dictionary which may be stored in DB or anywhere else

But may be conceptually you do not need to validate against enum in case values change dynamically? Jsu validate some Regex or more simplified pattern.